# Why is this custom font not being applied?

Tags: css, html, fonts

I downloaded a font called Helio from envato, but I can't get the font into my local file (haven't tried live).

My code is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helios_roundedregular';
    src: url('../css/fonts/helios_rounded-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../css/fonts/helios_rounded-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helios Rounded;
     font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This is a picture to the file path:
[image: picture]

I believe it's correct. The I have the root folder, the css folder, and the font folder which contain the font files. The img shows the css and font folders open

Comment: URL should be `url('fonts/Helios Regular.woff'`

Answer (score 0):

The file names differ from the font in your path.

change

```
src: url('../css/fonts/helios_rounded-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../css/fonts/helios_rounded-webfont.woff') format('woff');
```

to

```
src: url('../css/fonts/Helios Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../css/fonts/Helios Rounded.woff') format('woff');
```

Also, if your CSS files reside in the `css` directory, omit the `css` directory declaration.

```
src: url('./fonts/Helios Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('./fonts/Helios Rounded.woff') format('woff');
```

Comment: I copied this suggestion exactly, still no success. Any other ideas? Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 0):

your CSS files reside in the css directory, omit the css directory declaration.

src: url('./fonts/Helios Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('./fonts/Helios Rounded.woff') forma

Comment: I copied this suggestion exactly, still no success. Any other ideas? Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be using wrong name for `Font-Family`, try this name instead.

```
 @font-face {
       font-family: 'Helios Rounded';
    }
```

Comment: I copied this suggestion exactly, still no success. Any other ideas? Thanks for the feedback anyway.